# How can I make a shortcut to Gnome to login to a WWW-page?

Tags: gnome, shortcuts

Is it possible to crate a link to Gnome desktop that allows me to start a particular webpage that requires logging to the site and clicking some JavaScript buttons? I have a project in my work that requires logging to a WWW-site relatively regularly and often I have to choose one particular project.

Comment: Older Gnome versions (Gnome 2) allowed shortcuts to be created. e. g. You can create a shortcut that opens Firefox on the webpage that you want. However, I'm not sure about Gnome 3 since I have no experience in it whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one can open [Chrome](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) & [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) with an URL (eg. a regular `.desktop` file), while one cannot inject JS alike that. most easy is to use a HTTP debugger (F12) and then script it server-side with [PHP](http://www.php.net/) & [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/). if you really need to execute JavaScript, [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) can run it headless... there is still the alternative, to create a custom browser extension... which is being active on the one site, where the JS interaction is required (this can be defined in the extension's manifest). the [GNOME](https://www.gnome.org/) Desktop has in every case little to do with what is happening on some remote site, except telling the web-browser which URL to visit. the search term "Browser Automation" also turns up a few Chrome [plugins](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Browser%20Automation?hl=en) ...in general, one can use an actual web-browser or emulate the behavior of a web-browser (to obtain a session cookie and to stuff it into the local cookie jar, which equals being "logged in").

there is a slight difference, in between "logging in order to obtain some value and then store it" (where server-side automation makes perfect sense) or just automating the web-browser to perform certain interaction (eg. logging in and the handing over the ongoing session to the user). each site is different, so there won't be any default recipe; most web-sites not even adhere to standard `auto-complete` attributes.